# ios set contentsize of uiscrollview in Masonry

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, masonry

I use pure code (not storyboard or xib) to set size of all views, and I don't want to use hard code to set frame , so I use Masonry.

Now I have a scrollView and a set of views as subviews of the scrollview, the code is like this:

```
[self.scrollview addSubview:[self.imageviews objectAtIndex:0]];
[[self.imageviews objectAtIndex:0] mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.size.equalTo(self.scrollview);
    make.top.equalTo(@0);
    make.left.equalTo(@0);
}];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < maxcnt ; i++) {
    [self.scrollview addSubview:[self.imageviews objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImageView *previous = [self.imageviews objectAtIndex:i-1];
    [[self.imageviews objectAtIndex:i] mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.size.equalTo(self.scrollview);
        make.top.equalTo(@0);
        make.left.equalTo(previous.mas_right);
    }];
}
```

But here comes the problem:

1) How I can use Masonry to set the `contentsize` of the scrollview? The following code not works well because in rotate event, `self.view.frame.size.width` change.

```
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.imageviews.count * self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

2) If I have to use the upper code to set, how to deal with rotate event so the `contentsize` is update well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. All you have to do is set a right constraint on the last image view. By doing so you create a "connection" between the left side of the contentView and the right side. That way the UIScrollView "knows" how much space the subviews need and adjusts the `contentSize` accordingly.

There is no need to set the `contentSize` at all. Auto Layout handles this for you and it also works when rotating the device.

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/uiscrollview-and-auto-layout/) about this a little while ago. It uses SnapKit but that is basically just another name for "Masonry with Swift". The syntax is pretty much the same. It describes a vertical scroll view but the idea is the same on a horizontal one.

One more small thing:

Instead of doing this:

```
make.top.equalTo(self.scrollview.mas_top);
```

You can do this:

```
make.top.equalTo(self.scrollview);
```

Comment: Are you sure of this, buddy? If I do not set `contentsize` explicitly, the scrollview does not scroll at all.

Comment: 100% sure. It will start to scroll if set the right constraint on the last subview. The scrollview does not scroll because without the missing `right` constraint it has no way of knowing what size the contentView has to be.

Comment: Many thanks! That works. And your Blog is awesome, too.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Comment: If the height of contentsize less than the screen height,the scrollview can't bounces,and do you have any ideas?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. If the UIScrollView's contentSize is smaller than its bounds it does not scroll.